# realizar soma de valores codeiginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

Preciso somar alguns valores ao final de uma tabela conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: Exemplo 1]

abaixo segue os códigos que estou utilizando:

Controller:

```
function index()
    {
        $this->template->set('title', 'Lista de Orçamentos');
        $config = array(
            "base_url" => base_url('orcamentos/p'),
            "per_page" => 9,
            "num_links" => 3,
            "uri_segment" => 3,
            "total_rows" => $this->model->countAll(),
            "full_tag_open" => "<ul class='pagination'>",
            "full_tag_close" => "</ul>",
            "first_link" => FALSE,
            "last_link" => FALSE,
            "first_tag_open" => "<li>",
            "first_tag_close" => "</li>",
            "prev_link" => "Anterior",
            "prev_tag_open" => "<li class='prev'>",
            "prev_tag_close" => "</li>",
            "next_link" => "Próxima",
            "next_tag_open" => "<li class='next'>",
            "next_tag_close" => "</li>",
            "last_tag_open" => "<li>",
            "last_tag_close" => "</li>",
            "cur_tag_open" => "<li class='active'><a href='#'>",
            "cur_tag_close" => "</a></li>",
            "num_tag_open" => "<li>",
            "num_tag_close" => "</li>"
            );

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3):0;
        $data['orcamentos'] = $this->model->listar('ocod','asc', $config['per_page'],$offset);
        $data['total'] = $this->model->soma();

        $this->template->load('layout', 'orcamentos_lista.phtml', $data);
    }
```

Model:

```
function listar($sort = 'ocod', $order = 'asc',$limit =null, $offset = null) {
    $this->db->order_by($sort, $order);

    if($limit){
        $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
    }

    $this->db->select('orcdat, situacao, ocod, valor, cnome, pnome,numero,rnome');
    $this->db->from('orcamentos');
    $this->db->join('clientes', 'clientes.ccod = orcamentos.cliente');
    $this->db->join('produtos', 'produtos.pcod = orcamentos.produto');
    $this->db->join('representantes', 'representantes.rcod = clientes.representante');
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->result();
}

function soma(){
    $this->db->select('valor');
    $this->db->from('orcamentos');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

View:

```
<div id="list" class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Produto</th>
                    <th>Data</th>
                    <th>Situação</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>Numero</th>
        <th>Representante</th>
                    <th class="actions">Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <?php foreach ( $orcamentos as $orcamento ) {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $orcamento->ocod; ?></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $orcamento->cnome; ?></td>    
                        <td><?php echo $orcamento->pnome; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $orcamento->orcdat; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $orcamento->situacao; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $orcamento->valor; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $orcamento->numero; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $orcamento->rnome; ?></td>
                        <td class="actions">
                            <a title="Editar" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm fa fa-pencil-square-o" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'orcamentos/editar/' . $orcamento->ocod; ?>"></a>
                            <a title="Deletar" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm fa fa-trash" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'orcamentos/deletar/' . $orcamento->ocod; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Confirma a exclusão deste registro?')"></a>
                        </td>       

                    </tr>               

                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Valor Total: <?php  $total  ?> </th>    
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
        </table>

        <h3><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('mensagem');?></h3>

    </div>

</div>
```

vejam que eu criei uma função para realizar a soma do campo valor mas não consegui montar a query ao utilizar `sum` ele me retorna que não é uma função reconhecida do CI, minha ideia é que essa soma seja realizada também no momento em que o usuário faça uma pesquisa utilizando filtros por exemplo, ele filtra os orçamentos de X representante e ao final da lista a soma total. 
Se alguém puder me indicar a melhor forma de fazer isso agradeço.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sugestão mais simples seria gerar a soma na hora do loop:

```
$total = 0;

// Antes desta linha, adicione a variável acima
foreach ( $orcamentos as $orcamento ) {
    // Adicione depois para somar o valor ao total
    $total += $orcamento->valor;
    ?>
```

Caso queira inserir o sum na query, você pode realizar a seguinte alteração:

```
// De
$this->db->select('orcdat, situacao, ocod, valor, cnome, pnome,numero,rnome');

// Para
$this->db->select('sum(valor), orcdat, situacao, ocod, valor, cnome, pnome, numero, rnome', FALSE);
```

> **Nota**: $this->db->select() aceita um segundo parâmetro opcional. Se você configurá-lo como FALSE, o CI não tentará proteger seus nomes de campos ou tabelas. Isso é útil se você precisar de uma declaração de seleção composta onde o escape automático de campos pode quebrá-los.